# Iterate over image pixel and modify them

Tags: python-imaging-library, pixel

I am trying to move a pixel range (32x32) through an 256x256 image in raster pattern. and I've defined a function for that. I am using PIL

Could you please help me?

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
import os
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from collections import deque
import numpy as np 
import numpy as numpy
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from pylab import *
```

Using these libraries I have made the following function.

```
def raster_SCAN(img_re,pixel_1,num_scan):
img_w,img_h=img_re.size
for j in range(0,num_scan):
    img_2=img_re
    pixel_2=img_re.load()
    for i in range(8):    # for every block of pixels:
        for j in range(8):
            print(i,j)
            if i==1 & j==1:
                pixel_1 [i:(i+1)*32,j:j*32] = pixel_2[224:256,224:256] # set the colour accordingly
            if i<8 & j<8 & i!=1 & j!=1:
                pixel_1[(i-1)*32:i*32,j:j*32] = pixel_2[(i-2)*32:(i-1)*32,(j-2)*32:(j-1)*32]
            if i==1& j!=1:
                pixel_1[i:i*32,(j-1)*32:j*32] = pixel_2[224:256,(j-2)*32:j*32]
            if i==8 & j==8:
                pixel_1[224:256,224:256] = pixel_2[1:32,1:32] 
return pixel_1
```

Comment: exactly how is this not working for you?

Comment: I thought that I can iterate over the pixel matrix like when use image CV2 library. However, it seems not the case with PIL library